# Pytest: how to share database state between tests

Tags: python, pytest, django-testing, pytest-django

#### Context

I have following test schema:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestScenario:

    @pytest.mark.dependency()
    def test_step_1():
        database_mutations()
        asserts()

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=['TestScenario::test_step_1'])
    def test_step_2():
        actions_which_depend_on_test_step_1_database_mutations()
        asserts()
```

Where `test_step_2` depends on `test_step_1`, and `test_step_2` relies on database changes that occurred in `test_step_1`.

#### Question

How do i share db state between `test_step_1` and `test_step_2`? `@pytest.mark.django_db` rolls back database state after `test_step_1` end which cause test fail.

#### Actual code example

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestImpulseMachine:

    cls_name = 'TestImpulseMachine'

    # Workaround to share one test result for another.
    # This is what i want to avoid.
    @pytest.fixture
    def _test_contacts_create(self, authed_api_client, impulse_machine):
        return authed_api_client.post(
            '/api/v2/contacts/', {'machine': impulse_machine.pk})

    @pytest.mark.dependency()
    def test_contacts_create(
        # Given.
        self, snapshot,
        # When:
        _test_contacts_create,
    ):
        # Then:
        assert _test_contacts_create.status_code == 201
        snapshot.assert_match(_test_contacts_create.json())

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=[f'{cls_name}::test_contacts_create'])
    def test_orders_patch_for_amount_and_cryptogram_and_cardholder(
        # Given.
        self, authed_api_client, cryptogram, snapshot, mocker,
        # This is what i want to avoid.
        _test_contacts_create,
    ):
        start_cryptogram_payment_mock = mocker.patch.object(
            models.Order, 'start_cryptogram_payment', return_value=True)
        order = models.Order.objects.get()
        # When:
        res = authed_api_client.patch(
            f'/api/v2/orders/{order.pk}/',
            {'amount': 10, 'cryptogram': cryptogram, 'cardholder': 'autotest'},
            format='json')
        # Then:
        assert res.status_code == 200
        start_cryptogram_payment_mock.assert_called_once()
        snapshot.assert_match(res.json())
```

Comment: you can use a setup function to set all shared instructions within it. this will be executed before all tests. and a teardown to post executions : https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html

Comment: Although you can unlock the database via `django_db_blocker.unblock()` and share the db state in the whole test run, this is not the right path to enter. If you have some state to share between tests, move the code that sets the state up to a fixture that is reused in both tests.

Comment: @hoefling this is what i actually do atm, and it looks bad. I have following integration snapshot test and i want to exclude excessive _test_contacts_create fixture: https://imgur.com/dnTukvq

Comment: To clarify - i want to reuse result of `test_contacts_create` instead of prepopulating `test_orders_...` with factories generated data because it seems to be easier to do and maintain.

Comment: Please add the code as text to the question.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't see through the whole story, but here are the initial thoughts: 1. make the fixture `_test_contacts_create` class-scoped & autouse (`@pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)`. This way, it is executed once for all tests in class and executed automatically before first test in class invokes. 2. If you need the response of POSTing request in test, you can use `self` to store the results, e.g. `self.response = authed_api_client.post(...)` in fixture, then access via `self.response.json()` in `test_contacts_create` method.

Comment: Does this make any sense or did I completely misunderstand your problem?

Comment: @hoefling that does make sense and i'll probably do what you described, but i expected some solution which would allow me to avoid using fixture at all, since in fact i use it just to run first test code. It looks semantically wrong, i expected that there is a way to create general database scope, for example, using decorators. I actually expected that `@pytest.mark.dependency` can do that, but it doesn't.